# Netty: How many thread is accepting connections on a server port (80)

Tags: java, netty, nio

I know in Netty 4 that once a channel is established, all events handling for this channel is done on the same thread assigned to a particular EventLoop. This binding is done at channel creation time.

The part I do not understand is how many threads are needed to actually accept new connections and create new channels and do the bindings?

I keep seeing the following code:

```
new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
```

where the `bossExecutor` could potentially have more than one thread.

Does this mean under heavy connection storms, there would be more than 1 thread accepting new connections? And all these boss threads can simultaneously try to `accept` without synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread... In netty 4.1.x we also have support for `SO_REUSEPORT` which allows to accept with multiple threads by binding to the same port multiple times

Comment: So after 4.1 Netty does allow multiple boss threads to accept connections say on the 443 port? To use it I need to enable the SO_REUSEPORT option?

Comment: Our server during startup can have connection storms up to 10k connections. I wonder if I can use multiple threads to listen and accept on our server ports.